# Cannot use pivot_longer in r with multiple cell value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

Say that I have a `df`.

And I want to change it into a long data format.

I found that this question ([Long pivot for multiple variables using Pivot long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58665654/long-pivot-for-multiple-variables-using-pivot-long)) was similar with mine.

But I got an error when ran the below code. I did not know why.

What I expected should like the `df_expected`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(
  dis = 'cvd',
  pollution = 'pm2.5',
  lag_day = '2',
  b1.x = 1,
  b1_ci.x = 2,
  PC.x = 3,
  pc_ci.x = 4,
  b1.y =5,
  b1_ci.y = 6,
  PC.y = 7,
  pc_ci.y = 8
)
# df
# dis pollution lag_day b1.x b1_ci.x PC.x pc_ci.x b1.y b1_ci.y PC.y pc_ci.y
# 1 cvd     pm2.5       2    1       2    3       4    5       6    7       8


df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(dis:lag_day),
    names_to = c('.value', 'from'),
    names_sep = '.'
  ) # error code
# Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
# In addition: Warning message:
# Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 8 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, # 6, 7, 8].


df_expected = data.frame(
  dis = 'cvd',
  pollution = 'pm2.5',
  lag_day = '2',
  from = c('x', 'y'),
  b1 = c(1,5),
  b1_ci = c(2,6),
  PC = c(3, 7),
  pc_ci = c(4, 8)
)

# df_expected
# dis pollution lag_day from b1 b1_ci PC pc_ci
# 1 cvd     pm2.5       2    x  1     2  3     4
# 2 cvd     pm2.5       2    y  5     6  7     8
```

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: I updated the code and added the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>% 
pivot_longer(-c(dis, pollution, lag_day), 
           names_to = c('.value', 'from'), names_sep='[.]')

# A tibble: 2 x 8
  dis   pollution lag_day from     b1 b1_ci    PC pc_ci
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 cvd   pm2.5     2       x         1     2     3     4
2 cvd   pm2.5     2       y         5     6     7     8
```

in base R:

```
reshape(df, -(1:3),  direction = 'long')
```

or even:

```
reshape(df, -(1:3), idvar = 1:3,  direction = 'long')

              dis pollution lag_day time b1 b1_ci PC pc_ci
cvd.pm2.5.2.x cvd     pm2.5       2    x  1     2  3     4
cvd.pm2.5.2.y cvd     pm2.5       2    y  5     6  7     8
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But I don't understand why use `names_sep='[.]'`, not `names_sep='.'`.

Comment: @zhiweili in the world of regular expressions, `.` is a metacharacter ie a special character that has a special meaning. The special meaning here is that`.` represents anything. from letters to symbols to punctuations to numbers etc. But we only need the literal character `.` hence we put it in a character class ie `[.]` or we escape it ie `\\.` these two have the same meaning